«По некоторым оценкам» – вводная конструкция или нет?
Цитата из Википедии: "В Йемене, по некоторым оценкам, кат употребляет до 90 % всего мужского населения и 25 % женщин".
Спорю с одним редактором из Википедии, тот утверждает, что "по некоторым оценкам" не обособляется запятыми. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать и обосновать правилами.

"По некоторым оценкам" - обрубленный деепричастный оборот "судя по оценке".

Ответ справочной службы «Грамота.ру»:

См.: Предложения со словосочетанием «по некоторым оценкам» (КАРТАСЛОВ.РУ).
Почти во всех примерах есть запятые.

У Грамоты оценки, а здесь признаки.  Картинка совсем другая. https://kartaslov.ru/предложения-со-словосочетанием/по+некоторым+признакам

@Sharon  По-моему, вы перепутали вопрос с ответом другого участника.

По некоторым признакам — это наречное выражение, которое обычно является обстоятельством образа действия и не обособляется.
Обособление возможно, если оборот использован в значении вводного сочетания "судя по некоторым признаком".
Поэтому можно считать, что обособление факультативно, не запрещено и запрещено быть не может — по правилам Розенталя для обстоятельственных оборотов. Обороту не обязательно считаться вводным, чтобы быть обособленным.
В то же время надо учитывать позицию и семантику оборота в конкретном случае (для актуализации оборота).
Примеры
М.C. Аромштам. Мохнатый ребенок (2010)
В двенадцать часов дня папе позвонили из школы и сказали, чтобы он срочно приехал: Гришка на перемене подрался, и, судя по некоторым признакам (по цвету и размеру), ему сломали нос.
— От тебя, по некоторым признакам, требуется стать кем-то вроде монастырского послушника.
Игорь Сахновский. Человек, который знал все (2007).
Но, по некоторым признакам, жизнь была намного хуже спорта.

Sharon, вы комментируете ответ user 190920? Вопрос же о другом сочетании...

Правда?  Оценки и признаки так похожи.  // Тогда это старая песня – про мнения и оценки.  Это тоже не одно и то же. НЕ люблю однозначность! Машинное мышление и готовые ответы на все. Списывайте, дорогие товарищи.

Ну так в Йемене кат употребляют не по признакам, а по оценкам. И именно в данном предложении однозначное обособление.

Вот в Йемене  вопрос как раз и спорный. Есть ЦИФРЫ, откуда они? По некоторым оценкам.  Если подчеркнем, то обособим: по некоторым оценкам, а так кто их знает.  Контекст надо смотреть, о чем говорит автор. Мое мнение – обособление факультативное.

Спорный или не спорный вопрос в Йемене о цифрах -- это не относится к языку. // Употребляют по некоторым оценкам? Нет. Даже интонационно это сочетание хочется прочитать на другом плане. // Автор о контексте не говорит.

Я и говорю - старая песня!  Если нет желания понять, то убеждать бесполезно.  По некоторым оценкам - ДЕТЕРМИНАНТ, слышали наверное. Не надо его считать членом предложения.

А это разметка для чтения: "В Йемене по некоторым оцЕнкам / кат употребляет до 90 % всего мужскОго населения / и 25 % жЕнщин".

Если не надо считать членом предложения, то почему не обособить?

Не надо дробить предложение на мелкие части без необходимости. Обособить можно, если хотите подчеркнуть, что информация может уточняться.

Договорились, хочу. :)


ПО НЕКОТОРЫМ ПРИЗНАКАМ, наречное   выражение. Невводное, употребляется
в функции обстоятельства   образа действия, не обособляется: Но
начальство по   некоторым признакам догадывалось о приближении
знаменательного дня (К.Паустовский); Не к Вам, не к Вам ли я теперь
уже совсем почти испытываю что-то, что по некоторым  признакам похоже
на любовь? (М.Щербаков); По   некоторым признакам Налымов был почти
уверен, что Левант  привез ответ, а это означало, что Вера Юрьевна
жива...  (А.Н.Толстой).  Обособляется при желании автора придать
выражению особую  значимость, интонационно выделяется: Сергей Львович,
по некоторым  признакам, заключил, что граф будет просить взаймы, и
заранее мысленно  перед ним извинился отсутствием денег (Ю. Тынянов);
Он встретил своего
*остя, по-видимому, с самым веселым и приветливым видом, и только уже  Иесколько минут спустя Раскольников, по некоторым

